# Access Token is not renewed in Facebook Connection

Tags: windows-phone-8, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

After my Facebook login in Windows Phone 8, the access token is not renewed. What might be the problem?

Here is my FacebookLoginPage.cs :

```
namespace MyApp.Pages
{
    public partial class FacebookLoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        private string message;
        public FacebookLoginPage()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            message = String.Empty;
            this.Loaded += FacebookLoginPage_Loaded;

        }


        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            NavigationService.GoBack();
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        }

        private async void FacebookLoginPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(App.AccessToken))
            {
                App.isAuthenticated = true;
                await Authenticate();



            }
        }



        private FacebookSession session;
        private async Task Authenticate()
        {
            try
            {
                if (App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginInProgress == true && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                {
                    App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginInProgress = false;

                }

                else
                {
                    session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");
                    App.AccessToken = session.AccessToken;
                    App.appSettings["accessToken"] = App.AccessToken;
                    App.appSettings.Save();
                    App.FacebookId = session.FacebookId;
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/MainPage.xaml?token=" + App.AccessToken, UriKind.Relative)));
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                message = "failed";
                App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginInProgress = true;
                NavigationService.GoBack();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my App.xml.cs:

```
public static bool isAuthenticated = false;
public static FacebookSessionClient FacebookSessionClient = new FacebookSessionClient(Constants.FacebookAppId);
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of exception? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/279447e7-9f58-4896-97b3-5c6f668fde3b/renewing-facebooks-access-token

Comment: Nope, no exception. I can access user info and access token. However, my access token is not renewed.

Comment: You could find a detailed explanation here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388272/how-to-transparently-renew-the-facebook-access-token-while-processing-a-service?rq=1

Comment: Get method is not defined in the link that you provided.

Comment: Have you checked the Expire date on the Token to see if it is actually expired? Until the Expires date is reached the token will not be renewed unless permissions passed in the LoginAsync method are different from the previous Token permissions